# Sequelize a raw query, with COUNT, SUM, INNER JOIN, WHERE etc

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to change this raw query in sequelize.

I have trying many things but nothing works like expected.

For the moment i'm here :

```
ItemModel.findAndCountAll({
attributes: ['count', [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('rating')), 'sum']],
include: [{
    model: models.ReviewModel,
    required: true,
    where: [``]
}],
where : [{`items.connector->'SOLD'->>'name' = '${itemName}'`}],

})
```

And the raw query that i'm tring to transform is :

```
    `SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(reviews.rating) AS sum
        FROM items
        INNER JOIN reviews ON reviews.id = items.review_id
        WHERE items.connector->'SOLD'->>'name' = '${itemName}'`,
);
```

I'm really a beginner in sql req and sequelize ... Sorry if it's look ugly...

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize is not intended to construct such aggregations. It's more about CRUD.
It's better to use plain SQL query like this:

```js
const results = await Sequelize.query(`SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(reviews.rating) AS sum
        FROM items
        INNER JOIN reviews ON reviews.id = items.review_id
        WHERE items.connector->'SOLD'->>'name' = $itemName`, {
  type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
  bind: {
    itemName
  },
  
}
```